# Merging into large collections with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to figure out how to do something with Mongo with little success.

I am using a maReduce function to sum up power usage for a project I am working on. I have it summed up per account.

I have an hourly log of power usage for each account in a collection, and I use a map reduce function that produces another collection that looks like:

```
{
_id: (account_id)
value: {watts: (sum of all watts in existence in other collection)}
}
```

I also now use a mapReduce that does an incremental addition to this so I can just add to this aggregate hourly, rather than re-calculating each time.

What I want to know is how to rum something so that I can calculate the watt usage for the current year, and insert it into the values object in each document. Of course I would like to do this for every account.

I know how to gather the data via mapReduce, to produce a documents that look like:

```
{
_id: (account_id)
value: {watts_this_year: some_num}
}
```

I am just not sure how to merge it into the collecting I have produced.

I want to merge them to look like:

```
{
_id: (account_id)
value: {watts_this_year: some_num, watts: (sum of all watts in existence in other collection)}
}
```

Have I communicated myself clearly? Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to make my problem more clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapReduce is not meant for incremental updates. It's a one shot tool to churn lots of data and return a result. I would actually advice you to see whether using the aggregation framework is just fast enough to do this in real time. It is a lot faster than M/R.

For example, your above example would be represented with the following call to aggregate:

```
db.collName.aggregate( { $group: { '_id': '$_id', watts: { $sum: '$watts' } } } );
```

A/F is faster than M/R as it's implemented in C and can run concurrent jobs. A down side at the moment is that it doesn't output its results to a new collection, but that's currently being worked on: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3253